# ImageMagick on MediaWiki: Thumbnails not being generated

Tags: php, .htaccess, imagemagick, thumbnails, mediawiki

I recently upgraded my mediawiki site & moved it to a new server. I ironed out all kinks, and it was working fine. However the other day, thumbnails stopped being created successfully.

Existing thumbnails appear correctly, however when I try to upload a new image, the image uploads successfully, but the thumbnail is not generated.

Screenshot of Image uploaded page: https://cloudup.com/cjzizeQYLK1

This is the .htaccess file in my root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

This is the .htaccess file in my /images folder:

```
# Protect against bug 28235
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.[^\\/:*?\x22<>|%]+(#|\?|$) [nocase]
RewriteRule . - [forbidden]
</IfModule>
```

Thoughts on what could be going on here?

Comment: Have you checked your server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to whom belongs the `images` directory? The web server account must have write access to it.